# Question about Second-Party Transaction Malleability described in book "mastering bitcoin"

Tags: transaction-malleability, mastering-bitcoin

In book "mastering bitcoin", 3rd edition, page 136, there is a statement as below.
"Tx1 spends the second output of Tx0 to two new outputs, one to Alice for her share of the joint funds, and one to Bob for his share. Alice and Bob both sign this transaction before they sign Tx0."
My question is why Alice and Bob can both sign this transaction before they sign Tx0? because tx0 id(txid 0) is the part of data to generating tx1 id.

From the following statement on page 137, i thinks some improvements in which txid can be produced by presign, such as segwit technology in those transactions.
*If Bob’s alternative version of Tx0 gets confirmed, then Alice can’t use the presigned version of Tx1 to claim her refund.*

thanks!

Comment: For some reason they over-complicated it. The entire point is that even thought different BIPs and upgrades to bitcoin consensus/standard rules improved Bitcoin security and removed third-party malleability (so third party can't anymore use vulnerability of bitcoin not checking signature part of the script and change tx ID), malleability still can be made by a co-signer (second-party). It comes from the fact that ECDSA is based on random point/value, so for one message you can make a lot valid signatures. Thus, one co-signer can make its new signature, keep tx valid and by that change tx ID.